# Changing back to CPU with Google Colab

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am running a model on Google Colab.  The final step I would like to do is print an image, and show the top 5 classification predictions of the model.  Here is the code:

```
image = process_image(imgpath)

index = 17
plot = imshow(image, ax = plt)
plot.axis('off')
plot.title(cat_to_name[str(index)])
plot.show()

axes = predict(image, model)

yaxis = [cat_to_name[str(i)] for i in np.array(axes[1][0])]
y_pos = np.arange(len(yaxis))
xaxis = np.array(axes[0][0])   

plt.barh(y_pos, xaxis)
plt.xlabel('probability')
plt.yticks(y_pos, yaxis)
plt.title('probability of flower classification')

plt.show()
```

I am getting this error when I run this cell:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-d0bb6f461eec> in <module>()
     11 axes = predict(image, model)
     12 
---> 13 yaxis = [cat_to_name[str(i)] for i in np.array(axes[1][0])]
     14 y_pos = np.arange(len(yaxis))
     15 xaxis = np.array(axes[0][0])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/tensor.py in __array__(self, dtype)
    447     def __array__(self, dtype=None):
    448         if dtype is None:
--> 449             return self.numpy()
    450         else:
    451             return self.numpy().astype(dtype, copy=False)

TypeError: can't convert CUDA tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.
```

Is there a way to temporarily use CPU on Google Colab and in this particular step?  I don't really need to switch back to GPU because this is the final step in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
yaxis = [cat_to_name[str(i)] for i in axes[1][0].cpu()]
xaxis = axes[0][0].cpu().numpy()
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked!  I'm new to programming and don't quite understand the reasoning behind a lot of things work -- could you tell me the rationale behind how you knew to put .cpu() in those spots?

Comment: `axes[0][0]` and `axes[1][0]` are tensor that you get from `predict` function, so I moved them to cpu and then converted to numpy array (actually only the `axes[0][0]` needs to be moved to cpu and converted to numpy array).

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change

```
axes = predict(image, model)
```

to

```
axes = predict(image, model).cpu()
```

Comment: When I try that, I get the error `AttributeError: 'torch.return_types.topk' object has no attribute 'cpu'`.  I'm not really sure which aspect of my code would accept adding .cpu()

Comment: What does your model return exactly? What is the structure of `axes`?